# .htaccess rule to 301 redirect without parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have a problem with .htaccess rules:

I want to redirect this url:

`/productos/ficha/carretillas-termicas/dx.html` 
To this one:

`/productos/ficha/carretillas-termicas/grendia-es-serie-fd20-35n3.html`

I'm using this .htaccess rule:

```
Redirect 301 /productos/ficha/carretillas-termicas/dx.html /productos/ficha/carretillas-termicas/grendia-es-serie-fd20-35n3.html
```

But the server redirects to:

```
/productos/ficha/carretillas-termicas/grendia-es-serie-fd20-35n3.html?catalogo=carretillas-termicas&slug=gx
```

Notice the arregation of params "?catalogo=carretillas-termicas&slug=gx"

Both URL's are the same:

```
/productos/ficha/carretillas-termicas/grendia-es-serie-fd20-35n3.html?catalogo=carretillas-termicas&slug=gx
/productos/ficha/carretillas-termicas/grendia-es-serie-fd20-35n3.html
```

So, I want to delete the params to avoid two different URL's with the same content (a SEO problem)

The .htaccess rule that generate the "productos" URL's is this:

```
# Converts urls like:
# productos_ficha.php?catalogo=XXX&slug=YYY
# to
# productos/ficha/XXX/YYY.html

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ $1_$2.php?catalogo=$3&slug=$4 [L]
```

I tried some of the solutions I found in this site, but they does not works for my case.
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

(From the URL and rule you've posted you should be seeing `slug=dx`, not `slug=gx`?)

You have a conflict between the mod_alias `Redirect` directive and the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`. mod_rewrite is processed *before* mod_alias (despite the apparent order of the directives) and rewrites the request, appending the query string. The `Redirect` then issues a redirect on the *original* URL-path, but appends the rewritten query string.

Instead of using mod_alias `Redirect` directive, you need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` instead to perform the redirect. And this must go _before_mthe existing rewrite.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(productos/ficha/carretillas-termicas)/dx\.html$ /$1/grendia-es-serie-fd20-35n3.html [R=301,L]

# Converts urls like:
# productos_ficha.php?catalogo=XXX&slug=YYY
# to
# productos/ficha/XXX/YYY.html

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ $1_$2.php?catalogo=$3&slug=$4 [L]
```

To save repetition I captured the URL-path in the first rule (redirect) and used the corresponding backreference `$1` in the *substitition* string.

I also modified the regex in the second rule (rewrite) since it was far to general and very inefficient (requiring a lot of backtracking).